# Error while updating pictureurl property of Sharepoint userprofile

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Version: SharePoint 2013

I am trying to set pictureurl property for a user within WCF service. The main logic followed was as mentioned in this blog http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/how-to-upload-a-user-profile-photo-programmatically/

userProfile["PictureUrl"].Value = pictureUrl;

In this line, I am getting exception "The user could not be authenticated to the Web site being accessed."

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to update a user profile property, the code that worked for me:

```
SPUserToken token = SPUserToken.SystemAccount;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(currGuid, token))
    {
        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        HttpContext.Current = null; //clear the context for impersonation with token! mandatory!
        SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
        UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

        UserProfile prof = profileManager.GetUserProfile(userName);
        prof["My Property"].Value = "abcd";
    }
});
```

The part that fixed the error was clear the current context BEFORE fetching the profile manager.